# POST form data from codebehind to remote URL

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

Hi i am developing an application in which i want to POST form data from code behind to remote URL on click of button.IT should execute code from onclick event of button and post that data to remote URL with redirection. i.e. it should redirect to new URL after posting.

i tried to post data using web request as follows but it is giving response on the same page as it will not redirect to remote URL.

```
       string url = "remote URL";

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

        postData.Append(Encrypted);           

        //ETC for all Form Elements

        // Now to Send Data.
        StreamWriter writer = null;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postData.ToString().Length;
        try
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            writer.Write(postData.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }

        Response.Redirect("URL");
```

Comment: Maybe you get a throw error and never reach the redirect command. Do you have debug it ?